# Error when using a query as a function parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, functions, string-manipulation, string-splitting

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/) for creating a string splitting function.

When I try to run the function from the article using a `SELECT` as the first parameter,  I get the following error:

```
select 'Name' 
from   [dbo].[fnSplitString]((SELECT tbl.Field  
                              FROM   [dbo].Mytable  as tbl),',')
```

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a *query* into a function like that. How about using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT tbl.<KeyColumn>, f.Name 
  FROM dbo.MyTable AS tbl
  CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(tbl.Field, ',') AS f;
```

Of course in SQL Server 2016 there is native support for this now, with the new [`STRING_SPLIT` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql), instead having to write your own (less efficient) function:

```
SELECT tbl.<KeyColumn>, f.Name
  FROM dbo.MyTable AS tbl
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(tbl.Field, ',') AS f;
```

Answer (score 0):

So the **fnSplitString** function **ONLY** accepts one data value and splits into multiple values based of the delimiter you specify. In your case, the subquery you are running is producing more than 1 data value. The function will break in this scenario. 
For testing, add a top 1 to your subquery and you will see that it works. Also is your delimiter a "comma" in your data?

```
> select 'Name' from [dbo].[fnSplitString]((SELECT top 1 tbl.Field  FROM [dbo].Mytable  as tbl),',')
```

This will run but result will be 'Name' as your query is hard-coding column value as 'Name'. You probably want something like this:

```
select * from [dbo].[fnSplitString]((SELECT top 1 tbl.Field  FROM  [dbo].Mytable  as tbl),',')
```

Comment: Or, if you know that the `fnSplitString` function returns more than one column, and you want the column named `Name`, then `select [Name] from ...`

Comment: Thanks so much.  What should be the procedure for loop all the  rows?